# Angular 2 chain http requests with iterable array and merge resutls

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

New to angular and confused with the `flatMap` function.

```
export interface IProduct {
    productId: number;
    productName: string;
    versionUrl: string;
    versionObj: any;
}
```

### product.service.ts:

First HTTP request returns array of `IProduct` objects.
Make HTTP request for each product using the `versionUrl` from the product object and map the resulting object to `product.versionObj`.

`product.versionObj` ==> should be mapped to the result of each product's HTTP request.

```
getAllProductsWithAddlInfo(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
      return this._http.get('products.json')
             .flatMap((response: Response) => response.json())
             .flatMap((product: IProduct) => this._http.get(product.versionUrl), 
                     (product: IProduct, resp) => resp.json())
```

### product-list.component.ts:

```
products: IProduct[];

/* 
I would like to get an array of products with the additional info object 
mapped to versionObj from the http call for each product 
*/

ngOnInit(): void {
     this._productService.getAllProductsWithAddlInfo()
        .subscribe(
            products => this.products = products,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    console.log(this.products);
}
```

Comment: First you have to understand the different between `map` and `flatMap`. For example, `flatMap((response: Response) => response.json())` should be replaced by `map`

Comment: Sorry, i am new to angular/rx. From what i understand and reading about flatMap, i need to use flatMap to flatten the original array and use the product to get the additional info of that product.

Comment: .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]>response.json())

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Observable.toArray()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray):

```
getAllProductsWithAddlInfo(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(
        'products.json'
    ).flatMap(
        (response: Response) => response.json()
    ).flatMap(
      (product: IProduct) => this._http.get(product.versionUrl),
      (product: IProduct, resp) => {
        product.versionObj = resp.json();
        return product;
        // or simply: (product.versionObj = resp.json(), product)
      }
    ).toArray();
}
```

But change the debug function (at `ngOnInit()`) to print after the next event (otherwise it will print before the observer emmits any values):

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._productService.getAllProductsWithAddlInfo()
    .subscribe(
      products => {
        this.products = products;
        console.log('Products: ', this.products);     // console.log() move to here
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
}
```

[**Demo <kbd>plunker</kbd> here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zLeeaI0cjUYukRCpIvC5?p=preview).